# Get ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values

Tags: android, android-activity, hashmap

In my first activity I have the next code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_params = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> param_aux = new HashMap<String, String>();

            param_aux.put("language", Integer.toString(language_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
            param_aux.put("city", city_edittext.getText().toString());

list_params.add(param_aux);
```

And in my second activity I want to get the values, so my code is:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_params_ = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list_params_= (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list_params");

    System.out.println("...serialized data.."+list_params_);
```

If I chech the System.out, the values are correct sent but I want to get a specific value of the HashMap (example: city value).

```
...serialized data..[{weekend_midday_check=1, weekend_afternoon_check=0, weekend_morning_check=1, sort_by=0, language=0, weekly_afternoon_check=1, weekly_morning_check=1, weekly_midday_check=1, city=Terrassa}]
```

How can I get the value for the city sent in the first activity?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
list_params_.get(0).get("city");
```