# JSTL-Iterate in HashMap<String,Object> from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, hashmap, jstl

I have a map HashMap were define on the nex way:

```
 HashMap<String, Object> issue = projectM.loadIssue(id_tarea);
```

where the method 'loadIssue' call a store procedure from mysql. This procedure give back a list, then I convert the Hashmap in ArrayList> to iterate it in JSP. Now, I have the next line in my code:

```
   request.setAttribute("avance", Integer.parseInt(issue.get("done_ratio").toString()));
```

NOTE: `request` is an object from HttpServletRequest.

Here, I have an error, beacuse the .get method in ArrayList need a integer argument, then I saw this help: [Get ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082712/get-arraylisthashmapstring-string-values?answertab=votes#tab-top) and corrected the error putting '.get(0)' before the previous '.get':

```
   request.setAttribute("avance", Integer.parseInt(issue.get(0).get("done_ratio").toString()));
```

Then, in JSP, I have this code block:

```
    <c:forEach items="${issue}" var="issue"> 
      <div class="row collapse">
         <div class="small-4 columns">
            <c:out value="${issue['custom_field_name']}"/>:
         </div>
         <div class="small-8 columns">
            <c:out value="${issue['cv_values']}"/>
         </div>
      </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

This block iterate in ArrayList `issue` but I don't have any response.

Comment: have you tried change `${issue}` to `${avance}` in your JSP?